# Let $W=span(2,1+x,3-x,1+x^2)$. Find a basis for $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $W=span(2,1+x,3-x,1+x^2)$. Find a basis for $W$

$$2=\hspace{24pt}0x^2+0x+2$$

$$1+x=0x^2+x+1$$
$$3-x=0x^2-x+3$$
$$1+x^2=1x^2+0x+1$$

\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&2\\
0&1&1\\
0&-1&3\\
1&0&1
\end{pmatrix}

RREF: 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}

But this doesnt tell me which is the basis. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since all the vectors are polynomials I am just writing them in that way

Comment: Why not just use the standard basis of $1,x,x^2$ since $W$ is clearly $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbf{R})$

Comment: You should be row reducing the transpose of the matrix you row reduced. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the standard basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$, the polynomial $2$ corresponds to the column vector $\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Similarly, your other vetors have column vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$. You want to examine dependency among these four vectors so you can row reduce:
$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&3&1\\0&1&-1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. You will find the first, second, and fourth columns are pivot columns, so the original first, second, and fourth vectors are a maximally independent set. These make an adequate basis.

(Ultimately, your set spans all of $\mathbb{P}_2$, so any three independent vectors in $\mathbb{P}_2$ form a basis of your span. Including the three in the standard basis. But the above approach works even when the span is not the entire $\mathbb{P}_n$.)

Comment: Why should I be row reducing the transpose? If we have that the vector $[2,0,0]=2+0x+0x^2$, then wouldnt it make sense to put it in a **row**? I am confused about why you put as column

Comment: You are supposed to be asking what the dependency relationship is among the four given vectors. So, trying to find solutions to $c_1\vec{v}_1+c_2\vec{v}_2+c_3\vec{v}_3+c_4\vec{v}_4=\vec{0}.$ Write that system as a matrix, and it is the matrix I wrote (but with an augmented fifth column of zeros.)

Comment: Anyway, with equations like $2=2+0x+0x^2$, what would the unknowns be? $x$? Then you're not looking at a linear equation. The equations that get built into rows should have unique, independent unknowns in linear terms. Like for example  $2c_1+c_2+3c_3+c_4=0$ (looking at the first entry of the vector equation in my last comment).

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2, 1 + x, 3 - x, 1 + x^2 \in \operatorname{span}(1, x, x^2)$, therefore $W \subset \operatorname{span}(1, x, x^2)$. Note also that

$$
\begin{align*}
1 &= \frac{1}{2}(2)\\
x &= -\frac{1}{2}(2) + (1 + x)\\
x^2 &= -\frac{1}{2}(2) + (1 + x^2).
\end{align*}
$$

Thus $1, x, x^2 \in W$.
Hence $\operatorname{span}(1, x, x^2) \subset W$ and so $W = \operatorname{span}(1, x, x^2)$.
Since $1, x, x^2$ is a basis of $\operatorname{span}(1, x, x^2)$, it must also be a basis of $W$.

Comment: The questions asks which of the vectors form a basis.

Comment: I dont think you answered the question?

Comment: We know $1,x,x^2$ form a basis, but the question asks you about the vectors $2,1+x,3-x,1+x^2$

Comment: The question asks for a basis of $W$. I gave you one.

Comment: From the given vectors*, I will edit the question

Comment: What do you mean with "basis from the given vectors"?

Comment: @cpassos He means, construct a basis using (only) the four vectors that were given. So the task is to determine a subset of three of those vectors that is independent. Interpreted this way, it generalizes to when the span is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{P_n}$. A question like this won't always have the span equaling $\mathbb{P}_n$, and thereby making a trivial answer possible.